# MS ACCESS NZ Function Not Returning 0 (No Previous solutions I have found have worked)

Tags: ms-access, count

From what I have been able to find in the forums is it is something with my WHERE clause that is causing the issue but I'm not sure what.

```
SELECT Nz(Count(tb1lPersonnel.Status),0 AS CountOfStatus, tbl1UTCAssignemnt.RequiredAFSC, tbl2AFSCRequirements.TotalRequired
FROM (tb1lPersonnel INNER JOIN tbl1UTCAssignemnt ON tb1lPersonnel.ID = tbl1UTCAssignemnt.PersonnelAssigned2) INNER JOIN tbl2AFSCRequirements ON (tbl1UTCAssignemnt.AssignedUTC = tbl2AFSCRequirements.UTC) AND (tbl1UTCAssignemnt.RequiredAFSC = tbl2AFSCRequirements.AFSC1)
WHERE (((tbl1UTCAssignemnt.AssignedUTC)=1) AND ((tbl1UTCAssignemnt.[Suite#])="001") AND ((tb1lPersonnel.Status)=6))
GROUP BY tbl2AFSCRequirements.TotalRequired, tbl1UTCAssignemnt.RequiredAFSC
ORDER BY tbl1UTCAssignemnt.RequiredAFSC;
```

It results look like this

CountofStatus  /  RequiredAFSC   / TotalRequired

2 /1C171/2

2/1C852/2

1/1C872/1

What I need is the the requiredAFSC's that have 0 CountofStatus to Populate, Like below

CountofStatus  /  RequiredAFSC   / TotalRequired

2 /1C171/2

0/1C832/1

2/1C852/2

1/1C872/1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First things first.  `Count` does not return `NULL`. If there are NULL fields being counted, those NULL fields will not augment the count.
If you count a column full of NULL, Count will return 0.

Second, `nz` evaluates if `Count` returned `NULL` which will not happen, and thus will never return 0.

Assuming you want to count how many NULL fields there are in `CountofStatus` then you were right, the problem lies in the where clause. Your where clause will never return `CountofStatus`that contain NULL. Proceed as follows:

1. Remove the nz function cause its not helping.
2. modify your where clause to include nulls.

   ```
   WHERE (((tbl1UTCAssignemnt.AssignedUTC)=1) AND ((tbl1UTCAssignemnt.[Suite#])="001") AND (((tb1lPersonnel.Status)=6) OR (IsNull(tb1lPersonnel.Status)=True))
   ```